# Get response for check_ajax_referer

Tags: ajax

I want to show the notice to the user if the nonce check fails using `check_ajax_referer`. However, the function dies itself if fails. So I just wonder that if I die using `wp_die()` manually will that cause any issue or okay to use?

## Die itself

```
if(!check_ajax_referer('gs_nonce', 'nonce')) {
    // the response never sends as the function never reaches here
    wp_send_json_error(__('Do not be nasty with validation', 'group-shop'));
}
```

## Manually Die

```
if(!check_ajax_referer('gs_nonce', 'nonce', FALSE)) {
    wp_send_json_error(__('Do not be nasty with validation', 'group-shop'));
    wp_die();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's totally fine to manually call [`wp_die()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_die/) which works fine both with AJAX and non-AJAX requests. Just make sure you return a valid response body; e.g. if your JS expects a JSON response, then return a JSON-encoded string.

However, [`wp_send_json_error()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json_error/) is a wrapper for [`wp_send_json()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json/) which uses `wp_die()`, so you don't need to call `wp_die()` if you're using `wp_send_json_error()` or [`wp_send_json_success()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json_success/).

### Working Example

Client-side: Make AJAX request for an action named `foo`. Let's assume `ajax_vars` is defined via [`wp_localize_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/).

```js
jQuery.ajax({
  url: ajax_vars.ajax_url, // e.g. https://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
  data: { action: 'foo', nonce: ajax_vars.foo_nonce },
  dataType: 'json', // <- we're expecting a JSON response
  success ( res ) {
    // Request succeeded, but we've got an error from the server - e.g. Due to
    // an expired nonce.
    if ( ! res.success ) {
      console.log( res.data );
    // Request succeeded; no errors thrown on the server.
    } else {
      console.log( res );
    }
  },
  // Request failed - e.g. Due to an internal server error (parse/syntax error,
  // etc.).
  error ( xhr, error, status ) {
    console.log( error, status );
  }
});
```

Server-side: This function handles the above AJAX request.

```php
function ajax_foo_handler() {
    if ( ! check_ajax_referer( 'foo', 'nonce', false ) ) {
        wp_send_json_error( 'Invalid Request' );
    }

    // Run your stuff...

    wp_send_json_success( 'You may pass an array...' );
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_foo', 'ajax_foo_handler' );        // for authenticated users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_foo', 'ajax_foo_handler' ); // for non-authenticated users
```

Comment: Great answer. I have yesterday checked into the source and found that `wp_send_json_error` eventually is calling `wp_die()`. Thanks once again for great answer.